# Как лучше всего обрабатывать сообщения?

Tags: java, spring, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, callback

Я использую callback API, чтобы получать сообщения. Как лучше всего обрабатывать сообщения? У меня есть команды, которые выполняются не сразу (обработка видео), а через какое-то время (минута). Т.е. мне нужно серверу вернуть ok, а программа будет обрабатывать видео и потом вернет результат. Как это лучше всего и правильнее реализовать?

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }  


    @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    String message(@RequestBody JSONObject jsonObject) {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение задачи состоит из 2-х частей

1. Принятые от сервер сообщения надо складывать в очередь типа FIFO, технически это любая коллекция имплементирующая интерфейс `Queue` (очередь). То есть приняв сообщения от сервера его пихаем в очередь и выставляем сигнал "ок"
2. Далее обработчик сообщений - обычно реализуется в виде отдельного потока/`Thread`, который в бесконечном цикле проверяет очередь сообщений и поочередно их обрабатывает

В тяжелом варианте - это реализуется через API JMS, в рамках Spring это может быть например RabbitMQ, но это тяжелый вариант, поскольку RabbitMQ подразумевает выделение отдельного серверного контейнера и нацелен на работу с множественными клиентами и серверами.